# What is the importance of reputation

Tags: discussion, reputation

I know through reputation you can unlock other feature like review, vote down etc, but if you already have tons of reputation what is the purpose of that?

Comment: With great rep there comes great responsibility.

Comment: See [that question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296896/are-rep-hounds-necessarily-bad-people) where I state why having high-rep is useful.

Answer (score 17):

After gaining 20,000 in reputation, there are no extra privileges to unlock.

So there is no more extra benefit, in regards to participating/moderating in the site.

But, every upvote a user gets is a confirmation that they are being helpful to someone - capping reputation doesn't make sense in this respect.

Comment: There *are* perks waiting arbitrarily for the top whatever-percentile, dished out by community managers at their whim... :)

Comment: @deceze - though, if that's the stated goal of gaining said reputation... well... that would be sad.

Comment: No question there. I also don't think anyone whose stated goal it is to gain reputation only for the sake of gaining reputation will actually gain that much reputation. OTOH, if people can be "tricked" into providing useful answers by this mechanism... who's complaining? ;)

Comment: And imagine the number of massive bounties those people can give out with no loss of privilege. So that's a bonus.

Answer (score 4):

The two prior answers, while good, forget the benefit that you can use the reputation to award bounty to questions, getting more attention to them and possibly encouraging another user to find an answer.

Apart from that, it's mainly the privileges up to 20,000 - nothing certain beyond that.

Answer (score 3):

1. More rep means you get more privileges( i.e, you are given more powers on SOF to make it a better *Q & A* site).
2. More upvotes means *Your answer* is really good (and you might get a *nice answer* batch).
3. It **doesn't** mean that the person with a higher rep is *smarter* than a person with a lower rep.
4. Don't worry about rep (*much*), just enjoy answering questions, coz you really can't beat [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet)

Comment: Yap!!You deserve +1 for the third and forth one and _More upvotes means Your answer is really good_  !! Hmmm.. may be but it's not true for all the answers,you know what I mean. :)

Comment: @TAsk - indeed I do.. :P