# Are « rep-hounds » necessarily bad people?

Tags: discussion, reputation, privileges, help-vampire, rep-hound

I've been around SO for enough time to have come across several terms used here on Meta SO. Thus I've read about « help-vampires » and « rep-hounds ».

My definitions of those two:

- « help-vampires » are people who are only seeking for help, doing nothing but asking questions and are not necessarily people who help other folks to maintain good quality level on SO.
- « rep-hounds » are people who are only seeking for high level of reputation points, they aren't interested on others civic duties if they don't earn them a few points.

Between those two terms, I recognized myself in one because I have to admit I am the kind of user who is mainly seeking in having high reputation. Here's why:

1. [Earning reputation makes you access privileges on SO.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)
2. You gain credibility when you post answer and questions since I've noticed high-rep user' questions arent' as downvoted as new-comers.
3. You also gain credibility in the field of employment: I had once a recruiter who congrated me for having this reputation level for my work experience.
4. And last but not least, it feels good: it's kind of a global thank you from a whole community for having helped others.

I accept the fact that if some tasks here on SO aren't for reputation points, I don't do them as much as if they did. [Edits on posts which earn +2 for <2000 rep users when approved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85229/not-getting-edits-2-rep-after-reaching-2k-rep) tended me to do more edits than now (I still do sometimes).

So my question *is as « help-vampires » who aren't interested in helping the community, do « rep-hounds » necessarily have to be low-considerated people?*

PS: So I though I'd finish my post here but after having added tags, I noticed that « rep-hound » doesn't have its own unlike the other. Why? (*although I still don't have the answer, I took the liberty to add it by my own, as my rep level allows me to do so.*)

---

*Edit*: [so as per @Elin's comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296896/are-rep-hound-necessarily-bad-people?noredirect=1#comment206757_296896), I changed the terms for « rep-hound » as I didn't mean to insult anyone. English is not my primary language and I sometimes am not aware of the impact the words I choose can have on my audience (and was not aware of [this thread](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/226736/whats-a-less-offensive-substitute-for-rep-whores) on English Language & Usage either).

Comment: Bad people? Not necessarily. But are they people we want around, making lots of contributions? Probably not.

Comment: "Mainly seeking high reputation" isn't a bad thing in itself, by the way, if the answers you contribute on the way are of good quality.

Comment: @Pekka웃 How could they make earn reputation and **not** be of good quality?

Comment: @Deduplicator What characterization should it be then?

Comment: For example by answering instead of closing obvious duplicates and bikeshed-questions.

Comment: Categorizations like "help vampire" etc. are subjective. If there were a perfect way to prevent all contributions that are detrimental to the community, it would already be implemented. The thing is that there is no such perfect way.

Comment: @D4V1D: one of the ways to help someone is to give him the code. Another way is describing the problem and offer a solution. Unfortunately, the former is most likely not of any use for *others* with a similar question, but I've encountered code-only *answerers* that gather loads and loads of points, just because the OP decides it is "the most helpful" answer. (Where 'helpful' usually comes down to "I can copy and paste this and it'll work".)

Comment: I'd prefer such a question to be framed in terms of behaviors rather than caricatures.  Judge if you must the actions rather than the people.

Comment: I really hate that language. There I said it. I'm not saying you can't use it, just be aware of the impact it has on your audience when you choose to use it.

Comment: @Elin - I will second that opinion. it is pretty loaded language

Comment: @Elin I don't support it either. I'm using it only because I've seen it used elsewhere on meta.

Comment: @D4V1D I know it's used. There is a whole thread on [english.se] about it even. I just think it's good to be aware.

Comment: @Elin Right, I didn't know this term was controversial. If you can think of another one, I'll edit my post. Does "rep-hound" (from your link) sounds better?

Comment: The fact that people hate the phrase "rep-whore" doesn't mean you shouldn't use it when asking specifically about it. It's widely used and commonly known.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252077/839601

Comment: @gnat Thanks! I had read about that and I admit it made a lot of things much clearer.

Comment: @D4V1D New feature request: Trigger warnings on posts.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> *"So my question is as "help vampires" who aren't interested in helping the community, do "rep whores" are necessarily have to be low-considerated people?"*

Yes, because they constantly help in deteriorating the quality of the site, by giving the mentioned *"help vampires"* and *"going-to-be help vampires"*  the impression, they can ask any low-researched topic here, without putting in any efforts themselves.

If a question looks bad, and the obvious reaction would be to close it, it should be closed and not be answered (in hope the OP accepts it).

---

> *"You gain credibility when you post answer and questions since I've noticed high-rep user' questions arent' as downvoted as new-comers."*

That's more coming from the point that higher-rep users are asking the better (and On-Topic) questions.

Also you may have noticed that high-rep users may answer questions regardless of their bad quality. But not by means of fixing the OP's code (as it was probably asking for), but rather pointing them to their misconceptions.
I'm doing so myself sometimes, along voting to close the question.

Comment: What actions they do are deteriorating the quality of the site?

Comment: @D4V1D Clarified a bit more.

Comment: So a rep-whore is not interested in mainting good quality on SO. I guess there are also users who are seeking for several goals which are having good quality and high-rep. Hard thing is to do the right balance between the two. Maybe they can be marged in having a "global" good reputation on SO (not only by points).

Comment: @D4V1D: Didn't understand your last comment...

Comment: I think this is the main crux of the problem - is that the RW's might answer a *terribly* prepared question just to get rep. If I post a blanket "HEY CAN SOMEONE TIE MY SHOES"-type question, and a RW answers it.. then the whole site starts looking like more like MechanicalTurk and less like ... well, a "question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers"

Comment: @Deduplicator I was just saying that people can be driven by having a "global" good reputation here on SO, that means having high-level of points and preserving the good quality of the site.

Answer (score 9):

The question itself betrays a sense of uncertainty from OP about the matter. If you said, "Are graffiti artists necessarily bad people" then are already admitting that there's a controversy around them.

The big overlapping question, in the eyes of the community, is this - "What is in the best interest of StackOverflow.com?"

Yes, I have to echo what duplicator said - 
we need to be

> closing obvious duplicates and bikeshed-questions

Is it in our interest that we have 674 duplicate questions that all ask "What is the difference between static and non-static in Java?"

Is it in our interest to get a reputation for becoming an online sweatshop where people can simply dump code down and have it fixed?

It is up to each of us to gauge our own conscience. Perhaps the person who answers "GIVE ME CODEZ" questions is the only one who learns that material. I have long suspected that the main benefit to all of the top users here is *not*  this reputation, but solidifying their skills.

But ideally we would be a community of learners where people have opportunity to really learn the skills. With some help but not babysitting-type help. Guidance but not spoon-feeding.

Again, it is a very personal subjective question - "am I good person?".

good luck :-)